# To Group each value of one column with every value of other column using groupby in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So, I have a dataframe containing 3 columns each having 631 rows, so I am highlighting only the unique values under each column.

```
df

Segment Type  Nature of Query     Q1

PRIME         Request             1           
BUSINESS      Complaint           2 
PRIORITY      Critical Request    3
                                  4
                                  5
```

Now, let's say under 'Segment Type' i want to group 'PRIME' with every row of 'NATURE OF QUERY' and 'Q1' and find size, min, max, mean

So tried to use groupby func and i got this:

```
 df.groupby(['Segment Type','Nature of Query'])['Q1'].agg([pd.np.size, 
 pd.np.min, pd.np.max, pd.np.mean])
```

And, i got this:

```
    Segment Type    Nature of Query    size     amin    amax    mean            

         BUSINESS       Request          1        4       4     4.000000
           PRIME        Complaint        1        5       5     5.000000
                      Critical Request   3        1       2     1.666667
                        Request          31       1       5     3.387097
          PRIORITY    Critical Request   1        4       4     4.000000
                        Request          3        3       5     4.000000
```

What i wanted as output:

```
       Segment Type   Nature of Query      size     amin    amax    mean
           BUSINESS       Request            1        4       4     4.000000
                          Complaint          1        5       5     5.000000
                          Critical Request   3        1       2     1.666667


            PRIME       Complaint            1        5       5     5.000000
                        Critical Request     3        1       2     1.666667
                        Request              31       1       5     3.387097

          PRIORITY      Complaint            1        5       5     5.000000
                        Critical Request     1        4       4     4.000000
                        Request              3        3       5     4.000000
```

Ignore the size, mean, max etc it is calculated wrt Q1. My main problem is with the values of 'Segment Type' and 'Nature of Query'.

If any solution possible, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the data you're using supports the output you want?

Comment: Yeah it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Segment Type','Nature of Query'])['Q1'].agg(['size', 'min', 'max', 'mean'])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=['Segment Type','Nature of Query'])
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  Segment Type   Nature of Query  size  min  max  mean
0     BUSINESS         Complaint     1    2    2     2
1     BUSINESS  Critical Request     0    0    0     0
2     BUSINESS           Request     0    0    0     0
3        PRIME         Complaint     0    0    0     0
4        PRIME  Critical Request     0    0    0     0
5        PRIME           Request     1    1    1     1
6     PRIORITY         Complaint     0    0    0     0
7     PRIORITY  Critical Request     3    3    5     4
8     PRIORITY           Request     0    0    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pivot table function, see the tutorial here :

http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html